# Vanishing Index of an Unbounded Self-Adjoint Operator

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, unbounded-operators

The index of a not necessarily bounded self-adjoint operator $D$ on a Hilbert space $\cal H$ is "well-known" to be zero. What is the easiest way to see this. Moreover, does this automatically imply that the dimensions of the kernel and cokernel of  $D$ are finite, and does it imply closure of the cokernel?

Comment: Vanishing Index is one of several equivalent definitions of self-adjoint. Textbooks prove equivalence or leave it as an exercise.

Comment: The dimensions of the kernel and cokernel of $D$ are no necessarily finite, and the cokernel may not be closed. So those cannot be implications.